# How to inserty custom background or second plan footage using dynamic mask in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects

I need to change the sign contents in the [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2ZDpRwKaUA)

The problem is that in some parts gets "blocked" by walking in front of it Minions. How would you solve this challenge?

**Screenshots:**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like that is solved with "Rotoscoping". After Effects has several features that make this process easier. F.e. the "Roto Brush", you can find a tutorial about that here:

https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/roto-brush-refine-matte.html

Then you will have to track the translation and rotation of the sign as its carried around. When you have that you can add a layer that follows the movement of the sign that holds your new content.